# How to run a dynamically generated function stored in a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, var

I have a function that gets called from dynamically generated html, but its not being executed

The function.

```
$.check = function(s){
alert (s);
}
```

....and then... 
the value of the contents of the following function object is the above function's call.

```
value is  var s = 'hey';$.check(s);

function( event, ui) {
//////The following does nothing, not even an error
      return ui.item.value;
       }
```

How do I execute the function stored in "value";

Comment: i am not sure if i got what you are asking but if you want to call the function in `value` then call like `ui.item.value()`;

Comment: Nah, this whole thing: ui.item.value, has "var s = 'hey';$.check(s);" stored in it. So i want to run that.

Comment: eval(ui.item.value);

Comment: Ah, @CerlinBoss you typed your comment as I typed my answer! Sorry, dude.

Comment: That makes sense. Let me test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this in a browser is `eval`

```
eval(ui.item.value);
```

Node supports more advanced things like `vm.runInNewContext(value,{/* context */})`.

But beware of eval, it is dangerous. https://www.google.com/?q=eval+is+evil

Comment: Well this guy here argues the basis of it being evil. http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/

Comment: Yeah, lots of arguments about it. I am mixed myself, which is why I say "dangerous". I prefer to avoid it whenever I can, but cannot always.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, just do:

```
function( event, ui) {
    if (typeof ui.item.value === 'function') {
        ui.item.value.call();
    }
}
```

Create that `var s` as a function, like so:

```
ui.item.value = function () {
    var s = 'hey';
    $.check(s);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will seen as a function where u are checking if its a function, there's variable before the function itself.

Comment: But when you build that `var s` and the `$.check`, just wrap it in a function in your `value`